# The element of order 19

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

I need to find the prime number $p\le11$ and number n $\in N$, such as multiplicative group of field of $p^n $ elements consist element of order $19$. 
May be I don't understand anything, but if the group of order $p^n$ must contain the element of order $19$, then by Lagrange theorem 19 must divide $p^n$, then $19$ divides $p$, then $p=19$, but according to the task $p\le11$.
Can anyone help?

Comment: It *contains* an element of order $19$, not "consists" of elements of order $19$. The latter is not true.

Comment: It must divide $p^n -1$, not $p^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The *multiplicative* group of ${\mathbb F}_{p^n}$, i.e. ${\mathbb F}_{p^n}^*$, is cyclic with order $p^n - 1$. So you need to find $p$ and $n$ such that $19 \mid p^n - 1$, i.e. such that $p^n = 1 \pmod{19}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that
$$
5^9\equiv 1 \bmod 19.
$$

Comment: $191$ is the smallest solution.

Comment: Same as $7^3\equiv1\bmod19$, but it doesn't help really.