# Element of certain order in multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I have to find prime number $p\le11$ and $n\in N$, such as multiplicative group of field of $p^n$ elements contains element with order 19. Multiplicative group $F_{p^n}^*$ of field $F_{p^n}$ consists of $p^n-1$ elements. So I found out that for $p=7$ and $n=3$ there can be element of order 19 as $(7^3-1)\div19=18$. But I don't know how to find it. 
I would appreciate any help

Upd: I have recently asked similar question [The element of order 19](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764617/the-element-of-order-19)

Comment: It would be polite if you mentioned you just asked a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764617/96384, and make clear what is new in this question. So is it correct that now you don't have to find $p$ any more, but one element of order 19 in, say, $\Bbb F_{7^3}$?

Comment: You are almost correct. It is my suggestion that there can be element of order 19 in $F_{7^3}^*$= $F_{7^3}\setminus{0}$ (that's why I put $p=7$ and $n=3$ ), but I'm not sure that element of such order really exists in this group and I don't how to find it

Comment: Such an element most definitely exists, this is because the multiplicative groups of fields are cyclic.

Comment: One way: 1) Construct the field $\Bbb{F}_{343}$. 2) Take a random element $z$ from that field. 3) Calculate $u=z^{18}$. 4) If $u=1$ go back to step 2, otherwise $u$ is of order $19$. Do you see why this works?

Comment: Yes, I do, thanks! Have found it

Answer (score 1):

By *Cauchy's theorem on groups*, this  means you have to find a prime number $p\le 11$ such that $19\mid p^n- 1$ for some $n$. Indeed, Cauchy's theorem ensures the multiplicative group $\;F_{p^n}^\times$ contains an element of order $19$.

Now any prime $p\le 11$ will meet this condition, since it is equivalent to $p^n\equiv 1\mod19$ for some $n$, and this results from $\,p\in(\mathbf Z/19\mathbf Z)^\times,$ which is a finite group.